# query to update running balance without select query

Tags: sql, database, performance, oracle

**My Query Here**

```
UPDATE TBLBANKTRANSACTION  SET    
SU_CASHBALANCE          = (SELECT SU_CASHBALANCE FROM TBLBANKTRANSACTION WHERE 
TBLBANKTRANSACTION.ID=1)-2000.0
```

Can we update the balance without select query? or what is the simplest / better / fastest way to update running balance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not good at queries, but what if you do it this way

```
UPDATE TBLBANKTRANSACTION  SET    
SU_CASHBALANCE          =  SU_CASHBALANCE-2000.0  WHERE 
TBLBANKTRANSACTION.ID=1
```

Comment: the above works provided your **SU_CASHBALANCE** is not varchar